How much resources does my Google App Engine application consume when waiting for a response from an external API request?
I'm running Spring Boot on Google App Engine (Java) where I have a Task that calls an external API and upon receiving a response, it runs some code to processes the response. This external API can take 10-20 seconds to send back a response.
My question is, during that time my code is waiting for a response, are significant resources being consumed by my application and Google App Engine?
I assume that any data I have loaded into memory (such as the json data from the initial request to the Task or any Datastore entities I have loaded) is going to be taking up that memory in the instance for the 10-20 second. But what about the CPU or other resources? How many are being consumed? I am trying to understand how Google App Engine handles such situations efficiently.

Yes, you have an instance that is active and waiting for a response so you need to pay for that.

@minou Sure, but how much CPU, etc. is it using while it waits? Is it significant? Is there a better way to wait for a response?
